# The skill is a duplicate of an Alexa reference or template sample skill Error

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to publish my skill however the in the Functional Test under Certification I keep receiving 
`The skill is a duplicate of an Alexa reference or template sample skill.`

I have tried making the code appear more foreign to the algorithm checking it but it keeps bringing up the error. It says its a copy of the `Hello World` skill

AWS Lambda code:

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say what about ramranch';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Ramranch', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const RamranchIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'ramranchIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Lets enjoy a worlds most beautiful composition, composed by the great, Sunil Syal, <audio src="https://my-apis.000webhostapp.com/audio/Romantic%20Solitude-Instrumental%20(Flute).mp3"/> Wow, That is amazing. Click the link on top right corner to listen to full song.';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Ramranch', speechText)
      .getResponse();

  }
};
const HelpIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'You can say what about Ramranch!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Ramranch', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
        || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Goodbye!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Ramranch', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    //any cleanup logic goes here
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  }
};
const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
      .reprompt('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
      .getResponse();
  },
};

exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
  .addRequestHandlers(
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    RamranchIntentHandler,
    HelpIntentHandler,
    CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler)
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

JSON code:

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "barrysmod",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "ramranchIntent",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "what about ramranch",
                        "lets hear ramranch"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
```

I am new to creating skills, so any help is appreciated

Comment: You could start by being more textually robust in the following intents 1) Launch request, I would replace this 'Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit," with something more appropriate for your skill. Like Welcome to (whatever your skills name is) I can play a beautiful track of music by asking me lets hear ramranch or what about ramranch. I would also suggest that to get your skill certified you have more than a couple of invocations. currently, ramranch has two.  -more

Comment: also in ErrorHandler I would suggest that it suggests using one of the ramranch invocations. something along the lines in .speak and .reprompt like " I'm unsure how to help with that, If you'd like to hear some beautiful music ask me "what about ramranch" or say help and I'll be able to better assist you.  Go to my profile and send a message if you need more help!

Comment: @ChuckLaPress Hi Chuck Thanks for all your help. it is not possible currently on stackoverflow to message people so any other medium of communication you suggest would suit me fine.